# Firebase notification not showing emoticons in notification when app is in background or closed

Tags: android, firebase, webview, firebase-cloud-messaging, emoticons

when the message has unicode of emoticons like \u{1f600}, the notification will display emoticons, but when the application is in the background, notifications only shows unicode , not emoticons, I have searched the entire internet about this, I really need to show emoticons even though the application is in the background, any help I will really appreciate , thank you.